# Functional Equivalent of nested for loops to return a single item

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So I have this function looping in a nested object and returning the first item that satisfies the innermost condition. So in the end we would only have one (or None) object that gets returned. I tried using nested `find` but ended up getting the original payload. So I ended using the nested `for` loop approach shown below.

```
const getMostGranular = (facets) => {
  for (let facet of facets) {
    for (let item of facet.hits) {
      if (getMonthsFromNow(item._source.publish_date) <= 6) {
        return item._source;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Is there a more "functional" approach that would not look as ugly?

Comment: Can you add in some example input data and make your question a [mcve]? FWIW your code is readable, and you probably don't need to change it.

Comment: "Ugly" is subjective. This is pretty straight forward and efficient. Hard to replicate both of those aspects with a functional approach from scratch (meaning, if you have a bunch of helper functions already this may be easy, but the primitives available in JS by default would require a bit more code…).

Comment: You may have been using `find` incorrectly. I'd add your attempt to use that in your question.

Comment: one wonders what the value 6 can represent, it should be a constant with a meaningful name.

Comment: deceze's comment is also purely opinion based, of course: _Hard to replicate both of those aspects with a functional approach from scratch_

Comment: Loops are encoded as folds in FP, which is just another term for reduce. If you have a nested loop you'll wind up with nested reducers. If the result contains undesired nested structure (e.g. `[[]]`) you should also consider flatmapping. BTW, the last resort is always recursion but usually folds are expressive enough.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getMostGranular = 
  facets
    .flatMap(facet => facet.hits)
    .find(item => getMonthsFromNow(item._source.publish_date) <= 6);
```

Comment: Answers without explanation tend to get downvoted more often than those which explain their code.

Comment: `map` returns an array of arrays, you need to at least flatten that somewhere.

Comment: Edited to use flatmap

Comment: `find` will also only get you the `item` while he needs the `item._source`

Comment: Okay, I think it should mostly work now, *but* it's still a lot less efficient than OP's, since it loops over all arrays at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I think by just moving things into separate functions,
and leveraging stuff like `recursion` (instead of `for` loops)

```js
const getHits = (needle, [head, ...tail]) => {
  if (head?.months === needle) {
    return head;
  }

  return tail.length ? getHits(needle, tail) : null;
}

const getMostGranular = (needle, [{ hits = [] }, ...tail]) => getHits(needle, hits) ?? (
  tail.length ? getMostGranular(needle, tail) : null
);


const tree = [
  { hits: [{ months: 1 }] },
  { hits: [{ months: 10, }] },
  { hits: [{ months: 11, }] },
  { hits: [{ months: 12, source: { message: 'You found me' }, }] },
  { hits: [{ months: 13, }] },
  { hits: [{ months: 14, }] },
];

console.log(
  getMostGranular(12, tree),
);
```